# Assigning a value to a tri data type variable in Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, bus, system-verilog, tri-state

Suppose there is a 'tri' data type variable A declared in a module m in verilog. A is connected to the output of another module n which is instantiated twice inside m, in both the instances. In one instance the value of A will be 1'bz and in another instance it will be 1'b1. What value will A take? Could you provide reference from any textbook like Samir Palnitkar or any other?

Comment: @KingDuken Verilog does indeed have primitives with three-state outputs. They are the *bufif0*, *bufif1*, *notif0*, and *notif1*. See section 7.4 of the 2005 IEEE Std 1364. The phrase "three-state" is a **characteristic of the primitive** rather than a state; the letter Z or z indicates a **high-impedance state**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SystemVerilog, `wire` and `tri` are aliases for identical net types. Section *6.6.1 Wire and tri nets* in the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM explains that the driver with the strongest strength will use its value for resolution. There's no way for a net to have different values when connected through a port, but I assume you meant the driving value in each module. So the result is as defined in table 6-2, which is 1'b1.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I meant the driving value of A in both the instances.